# Team communication tool combining the advantages of Slack and Co-Meeting

Tags: chat, communication

I am looking for a team communication tool combining the advantages of [Slack](https://slack.com) and [Co-Meeting](https://www.co-meeting.com).

Absolute requirements:

- All content invisible to outsiders.
- Anyone with a "@mygroup.com" email can join my group.
- Channels can be visible to whole group, or invite-only.
- For each message, see sender and time.
- Channel notifications can be configured (eg. mute this channel)
- Keyword-matching notifications that override channel settings.
- Threaded discussion
- Text visible to all while typing.
- Several users can edit the same message at the same time (like in co-meeting and Google Docs)
- Jump to next unread message by pressing space or similar. Jumps to next channel when all messages are read in current channel.
- Messages can be edited after sending, but are marked with time of last modification.
- Desktop/laptop-oriented web site.

Less important requirements:

- Android app and iOS app, or mobile website.
- Integration with Github/Bitbucket/Google Code (commits and issue tracker updates appear in a channel).
- For each message, easily like/dislike/mark as task. Such marks are visible by all.
- All features also work with Japanese names (unlike Slack).
- Ability to mute a particular thread.

Can cost money.